# Laravel Framework PubSub

Tags: pypubsub

[image]Hi I have installed google pubsub library via composer in Laravel Framework

**$ composer require google/cloud**

Is this the right library for laravel framework. Has anyone used this library and successfully implemented pubsub.

Then I have created the topics and subscription. The Subscription is set as push.
Then When I tried to publish the message, I am getting error. In google, I can't find such error been repeated.
*Here is my code.*

```
use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;
$pubsub = new PubSubClient([
            "projectId" => $projectId
        ]);

// Get an instance of a previously created topic.
$topic = $pubSub->topic('my_topic');

// Publish a message to the topic.
$topic->publish(['data' => 'My new message.']);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Publish function must provide at least one of `data` and `attributes` members.

[image]

Comment: I have added the attributes , but still I have having same issue

public function publishMessage() {
  $projectId = 'projectIdname';
  $pubsub = new PubSubClient([
         "projectId" => $projectId
  ]);
  $topicName = 'projects/projectIdname/topics/topicName';
  $topic = $pubsub->topic($topicName);
  $topic->publish([
   'data' => 'New User Registered',
   'attributes' => [
    'id' => '1',
    'userName' => 'John',
    'location' => 'Detroit'
   ]
  ]);
  print("Message published" . PHP_EOL);
 }